# requery linq query based on filters

Tags: linq

I have a datatable I then want to query the table and filter the data dependant numerous times. I have the following

```
 DataTable results = new DataTable();

 //fill dt from sql query

 var linqResult = from myRow in results.AsEnumerable()
        select myRow;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilterName.Text))
{
    linqResult = linqResult.Where(r => linqResult.name.ToLower.Contains(txtFilterName.Text.ToLower()));
}
```

I keep getting the error

```
'EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>' 
Where name refers to the field name in the datatable
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: What is `fill dt`? is it some comment in your code? what is this `load`variable? `load` variable is not declared in your code snippet.

Comment: just updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory.

`linqResult` is an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` which has no `name` property. If you want to select the column `name` you can use the `Field`-`DataRow`-extension method:

```
linqResult = linqResult.Where(r => r.Field<string>("name").ToLower.Contains(txtFilterName.Text.ToLower()));
```